# Why is the Ruby capitalize method trying to call its self on an empty variable?

Tags: ruby

This is a class for an address book. I want to be able to call the `full_name` method. If there is no middle name then there shouldn't be a space displayed between first and last name.

I am invoking the `capitalize` method so that it will capitalize the first letter of the name. When I enter a middle name it runs correctly, but if there is no middle name I receive this error:

```
contact.rb:9:in `middle_name': undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from contact.rb:18:in `full_name'
    from contact.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

This is the Contact class:

```
class Contact
  attr_writer :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name

  def first_name
    @first_name.capitalize
  end

  def middle_name
    @middle_name.capitalize
  end

  def last_name
    @last_name.capitalize
  end

  def full_name
    full_name = first_name
    if !middle_name.nil?
      full_name += " "
      full_name += middle_name
    end
    full_name += " "
    full_name += last_name
    full_name
  end
end
```

Name without a middle name:

```
jon = Contact.new
jon.first_name = "jon"
jon.last_name = "bell"
puts jon.full_name
```

With a middle name:

```
hugo = Contact.new
hugo.first_name = "hugo"
hugo.middle_name = "don"
hugo.last_name = "boss"
puts hugo.full_name
```

Comment: What are the mandatory attributes that the user would definitely give?

Comment: If you initialize with empty strings then this won't be an issue and you can define full_name like this `def full_name; [first_name,middle_name,last_name].map(&:capitalize).join(' '); end`

Comment: But three empty strings has to be defined...:(

Comment: you would still have to reject empty strings to prevent extra spaces. ie ['a', '', ''].join(' ').size is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the full_name method you are calling middle_name name as well. 
So whether or not you provide a middle name it will call that method.

Please change your class definition like this -

```
  class Contact
    attr_writer :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name

    def first_name
      @first_name.capitalize if @first_name
    end

    def middle_name
      @middle_name.capitalize if @middle_name
    end

    def last_name 
      @last_name.capitalize if @last_name
    end

    def full_name
      full_name = first_name
      if !middle_name.nil?
        full_name += " "
        full_name += middle_name
      end
      full_name += " "
      full_name += last_name
      full_name
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error is because you're calling the method `middle_name` when you're checking for a nil value. on `!middle_name.nil?`

On that note, without too many modifications to your code, simply replace that method call to

```
if !@middlename.nil?
```

and it should work just fine.

Your `full_name` method should read like this...

```
def full_name
  full_name = first_name
  if @middle_name
    full_name += " "
    full_name += middle_name
  end
  full_name += " "
  full_name += last_name
  full_name
end
```

Note, you can simply just say `if @middle_name` instead of `!@middle_name.nil?`

Comment: I receive this error: `contact.rb:5: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`

Comment: That means you're calling a method that calls itself recursively and doesn't stop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the cleanest implementation of `#full_name` I can think of :

```
def full_name
  [@first_name, @middle_name, @last_name].reject(&:nil?).map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end
```

To prevent `String#capitalize`to be used, I would implement `#first_name=`, `#middle_name=` and `#last_name=` as this :

```
def middle_name=(value)
  @middle_name = value.capitalize
end
# you can now omit the .map(&:capitalize) part from #full_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Contact
  attr_writer :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name

  def first_name
    @first_name.capitalize if @first_name
  end

  def middle_name
    @middle_name.capitalize if @middle_name
  end

  def last_name 
    @last_name.capitalize if @last_name
  end

  # The full_name method can be refactored as below...

  def full_name # If plain Ruby
    name = [first_name, middle_name, last_name].reject{|name_type| !(name_type =~ /\A[[:space:]]*\z/).nil?}
    name.join(" ")
  end

  def full_name_rails # If Ruby on Rails
    name = [first_name, middle_name, last_name].reject(&:blank?).join(" ")
  end

end
```